# Object instantiation with all fields

Tags: java, object

I have some classes in my project and when I want to instantiate object from them using `myClass.newInstance()` to build SQL queries, it just creates the object with one field and I can't retrieve all class fields to complete my query. When I get size of my object it returns '1' instead of '3'. 
Any idea what should I do?

Here-under you can find one class and my query builder.

```
@JupiterEntity
@TableName(name="tbl_person")
public class Person {

    @PrimaryKey
    @DbColumn(name = "clmn_id")
    private int id;
    @DbColumn(name="clmn_name", length = 1024)
    private String name;
    @DbColumn(name="clmn_family", length = 1024)
    private String family;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family) {
        this.family = family;
    }
}
```

And here is when I want to instantiat an object from my class:

```
    public MySQLEntityManager() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if(ServiceLocator.getConfiguration().createDDL()) {
        for(Class entityClass : ServiceLocator.getConfiguration().getEntities()) {
            Object obj = new Object();
            try {
                obj = entityClass.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            stringBuilder.append("DROP TABLE ")
                .append("'")
                .append(ServiceLocator.getConfiguration().getDatabaseName())
                .append("'.'")
                .append(getTableName(obj)).append("' ");
            System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());

            stringBuilder.setLength(0);

            stringBuilder.append("CREATE TABLE")
                .append("'")
                .append(ServiceLocator.getConfiguration().getDatabaseName())
                .append("'.'")
                .append(getTableName(obj)).append("' ");
            Map<Field, Object> fields = ReflectionHelper.getValuesOfFields(obj);
            for(Field field : fields.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(field.getName() + " -> " + fields.get(field));
            }
            String delimiter = "";
            for (Field field : fields.keySet()) {
               String columnName = field.getName();
               if (field.isAnnotationPresent(DbColumn.class)) {
                    DbColumn dbColumn = field.getAnnotation(DbColumn.class);
                    columnName = dbColumn.name();
                }
                stringBuilder.append(delimiter).append(columnName);
                delimiter = ", ";
            }
            System.out.println("*****" + stringBuilder.toString());
            delimiter = "";
            System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that `ReflectionHelper.getValuesOfFields(obj)` isn't returning what you want. You can debug that, or use `obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` instead of some NIH junk.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Actually I've already used `obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` in my class and it works fine when I pass it an object. My problem is when I instantiate my object using `newinstance()`, it will be initialized with only one field (id)!